# Get child of box in a dialog in python Gtk3

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3

I'm trying to get a date value from a Calendar in Python Gtk3. The Calendar is inside a dialog. I have the following code:

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyTest(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Titulo")
        self.connect("delete_event", Gtk.main_quit)

        self.set_border_width(6)
        button = Gtk.Button("Open Dialog")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

        self.add(button)


    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = DialogExample(self)
        response = dialog.run()

        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            print("OK")
            a = dialog.box.cal
            date = a.get_date()
            print(date)

        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print("Cancel")

        dialog.destroy()

class DialogExample(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "My Dialog", parent, 0,
        (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
         Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        self.set_default_size(150, 100)
        box = self.get_content_area()

        box.set_border_width(6)
        cal = Gtk.Calendar()

        box.add(self.cal)
        self.show_all()


window = MyTest()
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

I cant seem to get the date value from the calendar. It gives me Box Object has no attribute box. I also tried using get_child with the same result. The box may in the future have two children, a Calendar and a other widget. How to get the date from the Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by properly using self.

```
import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyTest(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Titulo")
        self.connect("delete_event", Gtk.main_quit)

        self.set_border_width(6)
        button = Gtk.Button("Open Dialog")
        button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)

        self.add(button)


    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = DialogExample(self)
        response = dialog.run()

        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            print("OK")
            a = dialog.cal
            date = a.get_date()
            print(date)
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print("Cancel")

        dialog.destroy()

class DialogExample(Gtk.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Gtk.Dialog.__init__(self, "My Dialog", parent, 0,
        (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
         Gtk.STOCK_OK, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        self.set_default_size(150, 100)
        self.box = self.get_content_area()

        self.box.set_border_width(6)
        self.cal = Gtk.Calendar()

        self.box.add(self.cal)
        self.show_all()


window = MyTest()
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```